# SASS variable interpolation with React CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-css-modules

I'm working in a project where we are using React, we are writing our styles with SASS and then let webpack do the rest.

We just recently started using CSS Modules ([`babel-plugin-react-css-modules`](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules) to be exact) and the transition has been smooth, except for one thing.

Before the CSS Modules, we were utilising the BEM naming convention. It would often happen that we would do something like this, inside a component's .scss file:

```
$block: '.box';

#{$block} {
    //css rules

    &#{$block}--modifier {
        //other rules
    }
}
```

In essence we were making use of SASS's [variable interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____) capability, in order to write less in the case where the `block` level element's class name was big.

The problem is that as far as I can tell variable interpolation, for such a scenario, is no longer working with `babel-plugin-react-css-modules`.

I am getting an error like

```
ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed: Error: E:/Mitch/Workspace/Projects/testbed/src/index.jsx: Could not resolve the styleName 'box'.
```

I understand that with scoped CSS rules, there is really no need for writing something like `.box__list` anymore, since you can simply write `.list`, since it's scoped to the component, but just for curiosity's sake, is it possible to have SASS's variable interpolation work with `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` ?

Answer (score 1):

CSS Modules allows you to use locally scoped class names and animation names. This is its absolute functionality.

They have also provided a `composes` keyword because it helps maintain self sufficient component files within a single file without repetition. This works like SCSS `@extends` but differently. 
You can read about it [here](https://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules)

However, if you would like to use variable interpolation badly, you could just add SCSS preprocessor to your webpack config. `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` has documented the same [here](https://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules)

But, then it's just PostCSS, you can add any [plugin](https://www.postcss.parts/tag/sass) to suit your needs. CSS Modules doesn't care.

Comment: I am using `sass-loader` and `sass-node` already in my build process, however variable interpolation doesn't work. Anyway, as it turns out, variable interpolation is not needed at all, and this question is definitely a 'can I do it' type instead of 'should I be doing it' :) Thanks for taking the time to reply.